# How to append namespace before metric name in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I have static config in prometheus.yml

```
  - job_name: 'myjob'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['monitoring.api.endpoint.net']
```

And I recieve various metrics for example `cpu_usage`, `disk_write_ops`, etc. Is it possible to put them all into namespace like `compute_cpu_usage` with relabel tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
static_configs:
  - targets: ['monitoring.api.endpoint.net']
metric_relabel_configs:
- source_labels: [__name__]
  regex: '(.*)'
  replacement: 'compute_${1}'
  target_label: __name__
```